# JSON to CSV in python separating letters instead of values with comma

Tags: python, json, csv, format

I have been trying to convert a JSON fie to CSV in python but the obtained csv is very vague with each letter being separated with comma rather than the word as a whole from the key - value pair. The code which I have tried and the obtained csv output are given below.

**SAMPLE JSON FILE**

```
"details":[
    {
         "name": "sreekumar, ananthu",
         "type": "faculty/academician",
         "personal": {
             "age": "28",
             "address":  [
                 {
                     "street": "xyz",
                     "city": "abc",
                 }
             ]
    }
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import json
import csv
with open("json_data.json","r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f)
csv_file = open("csv_file.csv","w")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

for details in data['detail'];
    for detail_key, detail_value in details.items():
        if detail_key == 'name':
            csv_writer.writerow(detail_value)
        if detail_key == 'personal':
            for personal_key, personal_value in detail_value.items():
            if personal_key == 'age'
                csv_writer.writerow(personal_value)
csv_file.close()
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

> s,r,e,e,k,u,m,a,ra,n,a,n,t,h,u,2,8

Comment: `csv_writer.writerow([detail_value])`

Comment: also IndentationError. and this will give you rows with names folllowed by rows with age. You probably want to add the name and the age into a list and write that into your file. `.writerow(...)` takes an iterable (strings are iterables, as are lists)  and puts that as one row, seperated by your character of choice